# gradle issue: Could not get unknown property 'nexusUrl'

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I bought a new pc and installed all applications for work, added JAVA_HOME, GRADLE_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and the path for intellij idea, started to build the project and this is the error in settings.gradle

jdk: 17
gradle: 8.3
oc: windows 11
here the original error message:

```java
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'service-name'.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:121)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:43)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'nexusUrl' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
at settings_bc1q1ey1egubb3qbuwf2q4pew$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3.doCall(C:\Users\some-username\IdeaProjects\service-name\settings.gradle:5)
at settings_bc1q1ey1egubb3qbuwf2q4pew$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\some-username\IdeaProjects\service-name\settings.gradle:3)
at settings_bc1q1ey1egubb3qbuwf2q4pew$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\some-username\IdeaProjects\service-name\settings.gradle:2)at settings_bc1q1ey1egubb3qbuwf2q4pew.run(C:\Users\some-username\IdeaProjects\service-name\settings.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)

here are the original settings.gradle(I changed only service name):

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name "maven-public"
            url nexusUrl
            allowInsecureProtocol url.getScheme() == "http"
            credentials {
                username nexusUser
                password nexusPassword
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'service-name'
```